# How to set only one save button for a page with Editable Fields by Views?

Tags: 7, views

Using Views, I created a page that has editable fields(by Editable Fields Module) for Profile2 fields. Those editable fields have few kinds of type/widget of field such as Text, SHS(Simple Hierarchical Select) for Term reference, and Radio Button for List (text).

Now, I have a problem that few save buttons for each type/widget of fields are displayed in the page. The one is placed below SHS field and seems for saving only it, another is placed below the Radio Button field, and the other is for the Text one.

I want only one save button for all of fields in a page. Do anybody know how to unify those save buttons into one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Editable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) module. It uses one save button for all fields in a view.

**Editable Views:**

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited. Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save' button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.
>
> Currently, the following Views fields can be edited:
>
> - All FieldAPI fields
> - Node title